# Using Pandas to store spotipy output in csv (python)

Tags: spotipy

I wrote a code to store the output of spotipy into a pd.Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import spotipy
sp = spotipy.Spotify()

from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials 

cid ='XXXCIDXXX' 
secret = 'XXXSECRETXXX' 
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, 
client_secret=secret) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager) 
sp.trace=False 

playlist = sp.user_playlist_tracks('spotify', '37i9dQZF1DX5nwnRMcdReF') 
songs = playlist['items']

df = pd.DataFrame(songs)

df.to_csv('Songs.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index=True)
```

But theres a lot of output there that I dont need, so I found a code to only output the data that I need which is:

```
for i, item in enumerate(playlist['items']):
    track = item['track']
    need = (i, track['artists'][0]['name'], track['name'], track['id'])
```

now i can use print(need) to output exactly what I want, but I dont know how to store the data into the DataFrame.

If someone could help me that would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Append the output you need to separate lists and then load those lists into a dataframe:

```
# appending needed data to separate lists

for i, item in enumerate(playlist['items']):
    track = item['track']
    artist_name.append(track['artists'][0]['name'])
    track_name.append(track['name'])
    track_id.append(track['id']

# loading lists into the dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({'artist_name':artist_name,'track_name':track_name,'track_id':track_id})
```